# SSL setting require certificate and development

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis-7

I am working on a proof of concept. I need to configure IIS 7 and require certificates for any simple website or even just a page.

Is there a way to make this work with a self-signed certificate initially for development purposes?

[image]

I can get secure communication and access to page if I select to **Accept** client certificate instead of **Require**. When I select **Require** and navigate I get the following:

> Access is forbidden

(but with secure communication lock on address bar)

[image]

Comment: read this for a step by step guide: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates This was found after a 2 second google.

Comment: There is still a certificate error at the end of Scott's example. I do get a secure lock when I install the certificate but no page appears except error as shown above.

Comment: The warning is because it is a self-signed certificate which has not been issued by a Certificate Authority, so the browser is warning the user of this. You can still proceed to the site, and it will be encrypted over a secure connection. In order for it to be be trusted by your browser, you need to add the cert to your trusted store. Regarding the 403, are you certain you are connecting to the site via "https" and not "http"? If you force IIS to only allow connections via SSL, then a http connection will end in a 403.

Comment: I'm using https and all I'm doing is switching between "Accept" and "Require", then refreshing my browser. It goes to my page just fine with "Accept" but goes to error page with "Require"

Comment: check your logs for the exact 403 error that is being thrown. E.g. is it 403.7, 403.16, or another one?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/1418f820-b240-423d-a2e2-a8ecf6972354/http-error-4037-forbidden?forum=configmgrgeneral

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem issuing a self-signed certificate for development purposes, just get ready to deal with "This site is not secure" messages that your browser will pop.

I recommend reading [this ASP.NET link about self-signed certificates and IIS 7](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates)

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error you are getting is probably because you are trying to connect to the site via HTTP instead of HTTPS. When SSL is required in IIS, IIS will not redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS, but will instead return a 403 error.